# Xcode 6.1.1 UicollectionView and uicollectionviewcell in autolayout storyboard without a code

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, storyboard, autolayout

How can I keep same number of cells per row(3 per row) in different screen sizes with same space between them and changing cells width and height.
Is it all possible in Xcode 6.1.1 storyboards autolayout without typing a single code?
I want to achieve same as iPhone 4s in iPhone 6 plus too.

1. iPhone 4s
   [image]
2. iPhone 6 plus
   [image]

Comment: Did you find any solution ? If you have any solution please post it here. I need to have autolayout storyboard which supports iPhone 4S, iPhone 5S , iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus.